# Parsing a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, smarty

I have a multidimensional array in *PHP* that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 1
            [name] => Football Team Name 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 2
            [name] => Football Team Name 2
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 3
            [name] => Hockey Team Name 1
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 4
            [name] => Hockey Team Name 2
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 5
            [name] => Hockey Team Name 3
        )
```

The first word (of the array's key that is called *name*) I always use as a category title, thus, I would like to but so far couldn't figure this out of how to make the final output look like this:

[image: Output Example]

The solution, in my case, should be eventually used with *Smarty*.

I would be appreciate for any ideas over this.

Comment: The "proper" implementation is to not have logic in your templates ...

Comment: That I have. If I got you right - I never put(make) Smarty execute PHP from the templates!

Comment: I think wat @rdlowrey mean is that you should try to solve this problem using Smarty, even if you used only smart syntax, but like in my answer solve the problem in PHP. Not so much not to execute PHP in you templates.

Comment: I know, I agree and I'm not solving this problem using Smarty. What makes, you guys, think this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should prepare the data before parsing it to Smarty.

You could do like this:

```
$result = array(
    array('name' => 'Hockey Team 1', 'category_id' => 1),
    array('name' => 'Hockey Team 2', 'category_id' => 2),
    array('name' => 'Hockey Team 3', 'category_id' => 3),
    array('name' => 'Football Team 1', 'category_id' => 4),
    array('name' => 'Football Team 2', 'category_id' => 5),
    array('name' => 'Football Team 3', 'category_id' => 6)
);

$sports = array();

foreach ($result as $team) {
    $sport_parts = explode(' ', $team['name']);
    $sport = array_shift($sport_part);
    $team['name'] = join(' ', $sport_parts);
    if (isset($sports[$sport]) === FALSE) {
        $sports[$sport] = array();
    }
    $sports[$sport][] = $team;
}
```

This would produce a data set like this, which is easy to iterate over in Smarty:

```
array(2) {
  ["Hockey"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(13) "Team 1"
      ["category_id"]=>
      int(1)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(13) "Team 2"
      ["category_id"]=>
      int(2)
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(13) "Team 3"
      ["category_id"]=>
      int(3)
    }
  }
  ["Football"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(15) "Team 1"
      ["category_id"]=>
      int(4)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(15) "Team 2"
      ["category_id"]=>
      int(5)
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(15) "Team 3"
      ["category_id"]=>
      int(6)
    }
  }
}
```

An example at a Smarty template:

```
{foreach from=$sports key=sport item=teams}
  <h1>{$sport}</h1>
    <ul>
      {foreach from=$teams item=team}
        <li>{$team['name']}</li>
      {/foreach}    
    </ul>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Looks nice. I will run it and come back a bit later. Thanks!

Comment: Everything is perfect! I like it and it works like expected! :) Thank you!

Comment: What would be the best way to take the first word away from key `name`. Now the returned array looks like Football Team 1, Football Team 2 and etc., in the result I'd like to see only Team 1, Team 2 and etc. as it's already under the title Football there is not need in saying it again?

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev I've updated the example to do this. (not tested)

Comment: Maybe it's better to use `array_diff`?

Comment: A better way was to fix your data model to match your need. One model for spots and one for teams.

Comment: Well then it will require a lot of other changes to the whole code. I would do that if it was only this.

Comment: `array_unshift` solution doesn't work by the way! `Warning: array_unshift() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given`. Could you please also explain what is this for: `if (isset($sports[$sport]) === FALSE) {}` and when it could be `=== false`?

Comment: Yeah sorry it should be `array_shift`

Comment: The `if (isset($sports[$sport]) === FALSE) {}` is to create an array to hold the teams of the sport. It is `FALSE` every time a new sport is met.